# Yahoo dsp reporting api missing fields in dimension and metrics

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api

I am trying extract campaign related info from yahoo dsp reporting api.I don’t see campaign status field available in the dimensions.As per my understanding I have to pass the dimensionid of the fields that I need in the report.Does it mean I can’t get the status field ,If there is any way could you please guide me.